# Editable and non editable input field and select

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table, you can see it there: http://jsfiddle.net/webYa73/xuw23/

We can edit each row and save the changes.

I would like to see the input field and the select box also in the non editable case maybe with another font color, how can I do it in Javascript?

Comment: **What!** your still posting based on the same code, do your self a favor and stick with one thread and Others try to help

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? It would make something like this much easier.

For example: to delete a row - instead of:

```
e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
```

it could be simplified to:

```
$(e).closest("tr").remove();
```

Comment: Can you explain how it would make it easier?

Comment: Added an example. If there's no reason they can't use jQuery then an answer will be easier to suggest, rather than doing it with raw DOM code.

Comment: thank you for your help, the problem is that i'm a webdesigner and i'm not so familiar with JS, i found a javascript code over the net and i'm adapting it to my needs so it will be a little bit complicated for me to use now jquery